# Rowwise max/min in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to do something like this:

```
df['A'] = max(0, min(df.B, df.C - df.D))
```

However, I get a `ValueError` ("the truth value of a Series is ambiguous"), which I guess means that the `max` and `min` functions are doing some boolean operations under the hood, and this doesn't distribute over the Series. I understand you can get the min/max of some set of columns by e.g.

```
df[['col1','col2','col3']].max(axis = 1)
```

and so I should be able to get my desired output by way of making some temporary columns with intermediate values, but I'd like a clean solution that does it directly. How does one do this without having to make extra columns for throwaway intermediate values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`max` and `min` are built-in Python functions. They aren't designed for vectorised functionality which comes with Pandas / NumPy.

Instead, you can use `np.maximum` / `np.minimum` to perform element-wise calculations:

```
import numpy as np

df['A'] = np.maximum(0, np.minimum(df['B'], df['C'] - df['D']))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.